# What is an integral vector?

Tags: vectors, matching-theory

I'm currently studying the minimum weight $b$-matching problem. In the material I have for the problem, the author keeps mentioning integral vectors, but with no explanation to what it is.

An example is:
Given an undirected graph $G = (V,E)$, a cost $c_e$ for an edge $e \in E$ and $b_i \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ a parameter associated to the vertex $i \in V$.
The objective is to find a minimum weight **integral vector** $x \in \mathbb{Z}^{|E|}$, that minimises the total cost of the problem.

I can not find any mentioning of what an integral vector is?

Comment: Integral vector = vector with integral components.

Comment: @Wuestenfux - "Integral" not referring to calculus, but to the set of integers.

Comment: @mr_e_man Thank you both for the replies! My hypothesis from what I read was as you suggested, but I wasn't confident enough  to just use it without a definition. Once again thanks!